# ASP.NET Login Control cookies, how does it work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a login control set up on the site I'm creating and it works okay. I can query my database and it will login a user if the details match the database or fail otherwise.

Here's my code:

```
private bool UserLoginConnection(string user, string password)
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select userEmail from Users where userEmail = @user and userPassword = @password", sqlConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        string result = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        sqlConnection.Close();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

    protected void UserLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        string user = UserLogin.UserName;
        string password = UserLogin.Password;
        bool result = UserLoginConnection(user, password);

        if (result)
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
            Session["username"] = user;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
    }
```

My question is to do with cookies. My understanding is that if I check the remember me box (provided by the login control) the form authentication module creates a persistent cookie.

I'd like to know if my understanding of how it works is correct? I'm happy enough with the solution as it is, provided it works the way I think it does.

Note: I know my code might not be the best but I'm a beginner and I'm learning every day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

After **Authenticate** event is fired, it looks at the returns value of **Authenticated**.

If it is true, it creates **Form Authentication Cookie** -

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserNameInternal, RememberMeSet);
```

### AttemptLogin method of Login control

```
private void AttemptLogin() { 
    // ... removed for brevity...

    AuthenticateEventArgs authenticateEventArgs = new AuthenticateEventArgs();
    OnAuthenticate(authenticateEventArgs);

    if (authenticateEventArgs.Authenticated) {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserNameInternal, RememberMeSet); 

        OnLoggedIn(EventArgs.Empty);

        Page.Response.Redirect(GetRedirectUrl(), false);
    }
    else {
        // ... removed for brevity...
    }
}
```

### Other Thoughts

You do not need `Session["username"] = user;`. If you use **Form Authentication**, you can use **User.Identity.Name** to get username from **Thread's Current Principal**.

For example,

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: That's excellent, thanks very much for your reply. I wasn't aware of the User.Identity.Name, hence the reason I was using a session variable to hide a panel (in a portion of my code I didn't post)